# How to let an event handler inside of a function modify a parameter passed by reference?

Tags: powershell, winforms, scope, event-handling

I'm using functions to create different WinForm elements; for example, `RadioButton`s inside of a `GroupBox`. I'm trying to pass in a variable representing the currently selected `RadioButton` that gets updated whenever a new one is selected.

```
function New-RadioButton
{
    [OutputType([System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton])]
    param
    (
        [int]    $LocationX,
        [int]    $LocationY,
        [string] $Label,
        [System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton] $SelectedRB
    )

    $newButton          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    $newButton.Text     = $Label
    $newButton.AutoSize = $false
    $newButton.Bounds   = New-Object System.Drawing.Rectangle($LocationX, $LocationY, $RBWidth, $RBHeight)

    $newButton.Add_CheckedChanged({
        if($newButton.Checked) {
            $SelectedRB = $newButton
        }
    }.GetNewClosure())

    return $newButton
}

function New-GroupBox
{
    [OutputType([System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox])]
    param
    (
        [int] $LocationX,
        [int] $LocationY,
        [System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton] $SelectedRB
    )

    $rb1 = New-RadioButton $RBx $RB1y 'One' $SelectedRB
    $rb2 = New-RadioButton $RBx $RB2y 'Two' $SelectedRB

    $groupBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    $groupBox.AutoSize = $false
    $groupBox.Bounds   = New-Object System.Drawing.Rectangle($LocationX, $LocationY, $GBWidth, $GBHeight)

    $groupBox.Controls.AddRange(@($rb1, $rb2))

    return $groupBox
}

$Selection1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$GroupBox1  = New-GroupBox $GB1x $GB1y $Selection1

$Selection2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$GroupBox2  = New-GroupBox $GB2x $GB2y $Selection2
```

In specific, I'm using a script block inside of `$newButton.Add_CheckChanged()`, and trying to access the scope of the parent function to get and set the selection variable passed by reference. I'm not super proficient with PowerShell, I'm trying to write this like a lambda in C# and capture the scope of the parent. However, I know that this doesn't necessarily work in PowerShell - I've added `{}.GetNewClosure()`, but this only *copies* the current scope at *creation* time, not *run*-time.

I know that I could create script-wide variables (i.e. a `script:$Selection` or storing them in a hash table), but is there a solution that is agnostic to the name of the variable itself?

Edit: For reference, I'm using PowerShell 5.1.